# Why script doesn't quit if win32ui is imported

Tags: python, pywin32

I have a very strange unexpected problem with Python 2.7.2 under Windows 7..

This code doesn't quit:

```
import gtk
import win32ui
w = gtk.Window()
w.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
w.show_all()
gtk.main()
print 'stop-point'
quit()
```

The window closes, I get 'stop point', and all should be ok.
But console doesn't close.
Even `quit()` doesn't help.

The problem is in `import win32ui`
If I remove it, everything works fine.

Also, in version with just

```
import gtk
import win32ui
```

everything works.

What is the problem with win32ui?
How do I force my app to close?

It happens even without GTK:

```
import win32gui, win32ui

try:
    result = win32gui.GetOpenFileNameW()
except win32gui.error as result:
    pass
print result

# script ends but python doesn't exit
```

Comment: English is not my native language. Is it too difficult question? Or is my spelling to bad?

Comment: I think it's just that nobody knows the answer.

Comment: I ran into this problem today. It actually has nothing to do with GTK. even calling into win32 without GTK will make it fail to close.

Comment: I edited the question to include an example that doesn't use GTK. Hopefully someone knows the solution to this!

Comment: I filed a bug on PyWin32's sourceforge page: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3562998&group_id=78018&atid=551954

Comment: Can you still reproduce this? I can only get it to happen on my primary workstation, not on my laptop or server.

Comment: @Series8217 I refused to use GTK. Now I do not have it installed on my system.

Comment: @akaRem The problem has nothing to do with GTK; I reproduced this bug without it.

Comment: @Series8217 about problem. Yes, I found that, really, it is connected only with pywin32. But there is completely broken DDE in pywin32 in all versions after 2009 yr. So even if this problem is fixed in new versions, I still have it om my pywin32 v214 where DDE works. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by a bug in pywin32: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3562998&group_id=78018&atid=551954

I came up with a horrible hack that serves as a workaround until the bug in pywin32 is fixed. Put this code at the end of your exit routine. Clean up as much as you can before you execute this. The workaround uses the Windows `taskkill` tool to terminate the current task.

```
import os

# kill this process with taskkill
current_pid = os.getpid()
os.system("taskkill /pid %s /f" % current_pid)
```

Registering the above code as a function with [`atexit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html#module-atexit) might allow Python to do some cleanup first:

```
import atexit, os

def taskkill_this():
    # kill this process
    current_pid = os.getpid()
    os.system("taskkill /pid %s /f" % current_pid)

atexit.register(taskkill_this)
```