# Combining Tkinter and win32ui makes Python crash on exit

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, winapi, tkinter

While building a basic app using the winapi with Python 2.7 (I'm on Windows 8.1), I tried to add a small Tkinter gui to the program. The problem is, whenever I close the app window, Python crashes completely (getting crash messages basically).

I have found reports of this issue in several places, but couldn't find a fix or solution. Here are some sources:

http://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/bugs/443/#8bde

http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/134956 (this one is from 2002!)

It can be reproduced with as much as these 4 lines:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
import win32ui

root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

And closing the window after running it.
Does anyone know of a solution for this? Any recommendations for a workaround maybe?

Comment: Mmm, it might be the version I have installed then? I'll check mine when I get the chance to boot up my windows machine

Comment: @eyalzek, I get the same crash as you. Happens only when win32ui is imported, and Tk tries to close a window. I repro'd it on multiple machines (using Windows Server 2008).

Comment: I've also had this error in the past, I ended up resorting to using only Tkinter to avoid it. Clearly there is some conflict in window management/UI stuff... I don't know if its avoidable in your case but I always stick to one framework from the outset if I have the option.

Comment: I just checked on Py 3.6.4, and it looks like this issue may have gone away. I think it was still in Py 3.6.3. Anyone want to confirm that this issue is solved with Python 3.6.4 and PyWin32-221?

Comment: Exist [the "horrible hack" solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467225/why-script-doesnt-quit-if-win32ui-is-imported).

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to invoke the *Tkinter-win32UI app* with **pythonw**. Python doesn't crash.

Tested with Python 3.6.3 on Win 10.

Answer (score 0):

Make a button on the Windows and close your program by this button. Here's my script:

```
from tkinter import *
import win32ui

win = Tk()
frame = Frame(win)
frame.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)
b1 = Button(frame, text = "Close", command = win.destroy)
b1.pack()
win.mainloop()
```