# PyQt5 crash on exit when win32ui imported

Tags: python, pyqt, pywin32

I discovered a conflict with PyQt5 and pywin32's win32ui module.

I'm on:

- Windows 10, 64-bit
- 64-bit Python 3.6.4 (via Anaconda)
- PyQt 5.6
- pywin32 223

When I run the following minimal example, I get 2 python.exe crash notifications on exit (after closing the "Hello" window). If I comment out the win32ui import, the crash does not occur.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import win32ui

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello")
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

I found what I think is the bug here: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/675, though I don't know how to confirm this.  According to this it's related to hooks that win32ui uses to monitor all the active windows.  The bug doesn't appear to have been resolved.

I see another related issue here: [Combining Tkinter and win32ui makes Python crash on exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723648/combining-tkinter-and-win32ui-makes-python-crash-on-exit)

Any suggestions on workarounds for this?  I was using win32ui as part of capturing a screenshot, which I can do through other means, but it's an annoying bug regardless.  Interestingly, it doesn't crash on exit in PyCharm's debugger.  I'm guessing the debugger changes how the python interpreter shutdown process works (or keeps the interpreter alive for longer) which prevents the bug from occurring.

Comment: Can't reproduce on `pywin32==223, PyQt5==5.10.1 Python 3.6.4 x86 windows7-64`

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm using pywin32==221, PyQt5==5.10, Python x64 on windows 7-64.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens to me and not to BPL with almost the same setup. It could be that it works on 32 bit python and doesn't work on 64 bit python.